# The player gravity decreases when I add linear damping

Tags: c++, box2d

Recently I added `p_pBody.body->SetLinearDamping(8.0f);` code to my player's instantiate code to prevent my player from sliding after I move right or left.

Now the gravity feels so low, like 2.0f or something.

I can fix this problem by increasing the world's gravity, but the other box2d objects' gravity would increase too. So what can I do?

Comment: I know [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/wiki/Body:setLinearDamping) suggests to limit this value to 0.1. Maybe you could dynamically increase the friction between the character and the ground when the user releases the "move" buttons, and decrease it when the player is moving instead?

Comment: wdym by saying  "increase the friction between the character and the ground" should i increase the ground or player

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot that box2d does not have parameters per "pairs"... This suggestion of mine is not good.

Comment: i did the thing for player's collider, but now the player is bounces while moving.